# commandline call from java

Tags: java, process, cmd

I'm looking to call the command line from a java program. I have successfully entered the command line using this bit of code

```
String[] cmd = new String[2];            
cmd[0] = "cmd /c dir";

Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
System.out.println("Execing " + cmd[0]);
Process proc = rt.exec(cmd[0]);
```

However, the actual commands aren't working. I am not too familiar with command line, I have only ever typed directly into it. So my question is how do I pass multiple arguments in? For instance if I wanted to change to C:\ I would have thought I could just add cd\ on the end but this doesn't seem to work?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `&` symbol.  Everything needs to go in at once.  For instance: `cd .. & echo "test"` will go to the previous directory and then echo test.

Taken from here: http://forums.techguy.org/dos-other/697113-solved-multiple-commands-cmd.html